# cleanQueue - cleanup function. C++

Tags: c++, struct, queue, stack

Hi so I have a task to create a full queue with integers
I need to do a clean function like that:

```
`void cleanQueue(Queue* q);
`
```

The Queue form is that:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
  int * arr;
} Queue;
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: It depends on how you are initializing `int *arr` of structure `Queue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you need the implemenatation to be like:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
  int * arr;
} Queue;
```

you could simply do:

```
void cleanQueue(Queue* q)
{
  delete q->arr;
}
```

or if you initialise the arr data member as an array like `{1, 2, 3, 4}`you would do it like this;

```
void cleanQueue(Queue* q)
{
  delete[] q->arr;
}
```

So you're program would be:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
  int * arr;
} Queue;

void cleanQueue(Queue* q)
{
    delete q->arr;
}

int main()
{
    // ... Do something
}
```

Basically what is happening is you are accessing the `arr` of the Queue using the `->` operator and deleting the pointer to int: `int* arr`.

Comment: But if you didn't need to do: typedef struct Queue
{
  int * arr;
} Queue; it would be simpler to just handle it in the destructor because you dont have to maually call CleanQueue : as soon as it goes out of scope the desturctor would be called.

Comment: Does the delete section clearing the array or deleting the array?

Comment: oh sorry it deletes the array. Is that what you want or do you just want to set the values to 0?

Comment: Yes, I mean I dont really know what am I supposed to do. But I know that after im clearing the array I should put new values.

Comment: well I think I should do the pop function then use it inside the clear one.

Comment: You could just do instead of delete: `q->arr = {};`. Which clears it.

Comment: Oh tysm for you help and your time!